# What is the expected input for uninterestingTags in osmtogeojson?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api

I am currently working with `Leaflet.js` and `Overpass API` and I am using `osmtogeojson` to do the format change between the OSM-JSON that Overpass API outputs and the GeoJSON that Leaflet.js needs as input. To do so I am using the following code:

```
data = osmtogeojson(osm_data);
```

This works perfectly.

**Here comes the problem:** I am trying to ignore some data that I am getting on the OSM-JSON dataset. So I am trying to use `uninterestingTags` as given in the [osmtogeojson API](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson#api). The thing is that I don't know how to code this thing. This is not working:

```
 data = osmtogeojson(
      osm_data, uninterestingTags = {"source"}
 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the tag to *true*, as done [here](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson/blob/2.0.0/index.js#L14-L24):

`uninterestingTags = {"source": true}`.

Comment: This seems to be working. Warning: It only ignores unconnected nodes. If the node is part of a way, it's taken anyways (otherwise, most ways would be void as most of their nodes have no tags).